# Scaling of TrueType font leads to blurry text?

Tags: c++, opengl, truetype, freetype

I am using FreeType to render text. I have been told that TrueType relies on math and thus should not get blurry when scaled like bitmap fonts. However, this is exactly what happens for me.

What I do is that I first initialize a 'face' in FreeType and then store the generated glyph bitmap in a texture. Then I scale that texture by 4 and render it - and it looks blurry!

So here is what I have done (approximately):

```
FT_Face face;
if(FT_New_Face(ft, "fonts/arial.ttf", 0, &face))
    std::cout << "Failed to load font\n";
```

then generated a texture

```
unsigned int texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, face->glyph->bitmap.width,
    face->glyph->bitmap.rows, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, face->glyph->bitmap.buffer);
```

which is then scaled by stretching the texture over a bigger quad...

So why does my TrueType font turn blurry when scaling just like bitmap fonts?

Comment: Because freetype renders the glyphs to a texture, and stretching this is entirely equivalent to stretching a bitmap.

Comment: There's not enough information here to tell you why exactly, we'd need to see your drawing code. As it is you're creating a texture with the same dimensions as the bitmap generated for a specific glyph (at whatever font size you've set, it's not shown). If you then draw this texture to say a screen space quad so that the rendered quad takes up more screen pixels than the texture has texels, the hardware will perform scaling. By default this will be linear interpolation which produces a blurry look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bitmap fonts get blurry when scaled because they're bitmaps. The blur comes from the fact that scaling them up from their natural resolution requires inventing new pixel information where the bitmap has none. That "new information" is the blurry part.

Textures are bitmaps (more or less). So when you transform a True-Type font into a texture, it *becomes* a bitmap. Textures can't reach back into what created them to manufacture that new information. They have the information they have at the time you uploaded data into them, based on the resolution you give them.

So regardless of how a texture gets its data, it will behave on scaling like the bitmap that it is: by getting blurry.

If you intend to exploit TrueType's multi-resolution nature, then you need to generate glyphs at the resolution you expect to draw them. Or you can employ [signed-distance font rasterization](https://blog.mapbox.com/drawing-text-with-signed-distance-fields-in-mapbox-gl-b0933af6f817).

Comment: Thank you, but regarding "then you need to generate glyphs at the resolution you expect to draw them" - I have no idea how to do that (have tried many things).. Like, how can I set the scale of those glyphs BEFORE they are generated into bitmaps then (without using the signed-distance font rasterization as you mention)?

Comment: @sostack: But you did that already. It's in the code that produced a valid `face->glyph`. You didn't show us you doing that, so I can't point it out for you, but at some point in your code, you told FreeType "I want the glyph for character X". Somewhere in the asking, you told FreeType how *big* to make that character. Possibly some "set font size" function or somesuch.